# MySQL Repeatable Read and dirty reads

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking

According to this [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Repeatable_reads), the repeatable read isolation level holds read and write locks when selecting data.

My understanding is that this can prevent the age old banking example:

1. Start a transaction
2. Get (SELECT) account balance ($100)
3. Withdraw $10 and UPDATE new value ($90)
4. Commit transaction

If in between 2 & 3 the customer receives a deposit of $1000, that transaction should be blocked because of the read/write lock acquired in step 2. Otherwise, step 3 would write $90 instead of $1090.

However, according to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read), repeatable read (default) works differently. All it ensures is that no matter how many SELECTs we do, we get the same value, regardless whether the value has been changed by another transaction. Also other transactions are allowed to modify the values we read.

This sounds broken, not sure why I would want to read an old balance. The doc says that an explicit FOR UPDATE needs to be added to the SELECT to acquire the appropriate locks.

I'm confused about the definition and implementation of repeatable read. Could somebody clarify how the banking problem is solved?

Comment: You would not use a repeatable read in this case... in fact if you are in a transaction it does not make sense to use a repeatable read.  Repeatable read is used to "get around" others changing the data while you don't want to make a lock, but you also don't want your data to change.

Comment: Repeatable read is very useful when you are creating a report which you want to be internally consistent at a point in time.  Not so useful if you are updating a banking account.

Answer (score 1):

I'll talk about how it works in MySQL and PostgreSQL, since I'm not as familiar with other SQL implementations. In the banking example you gave, the following should be noted:

- the deposit would *not* be blocked. Repeatable read isolation does not prevent concurrent changes in another transaction. It only dictates how *read* operations will behave within a transaction. Namely, as you said, read operations get a frozen version of the database, from the time the transaction began.
- the withdraw operation in step 3, however, *would* be blocked by the deposit operation, and would have to wait until the deposit transaction has been committed. This kind of lock happens on all transaction isolation levels, even the least conservative (read uncommitted), because changes to data are involved.

Now, the resulting balance after both transactions are finished will depend on how you write your statements. With a SQL statement for the withdrawal step done as follows,

```sql
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 10 WHERE id = 10;
```

the final balance will be $1090. MySQL/PostgreSQL will realize the data has changed in another transaction, and the withdrawal will thus use the latest value, even though the `UPDATE` statement was called within a "repeatable read" transaction.

If you, however, subtract $10 from the $100 you got from step 2 in code, and then run the withdrawal like this

```sql
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 90 WHERE id = 10;
```

the transaction isolation won't help, and the balance will end up being $90.